# How to fetch data send from curl command?

Tags: curl

Let's say I have the following request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d 'Hello, World!' http://localhost:3000/1/files/test.txt
```

In the cases when the data was sent in the key/value form (i.e. -d 'test: 123') I could get the value of test with params[:test]. BTW, I need this for my API. But, with only **params**, as I guessed at first, I can't get the "Hello, World!" string, for further processing. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was **request.body.read**. (in Ruby)